# Add a line in a file at multiple places upon condition using Ansible

Tags: regex, file, insert, ansible

I wish to add the line "Hi There" in file1.txt after i find a line that starts with Directory tag if it is already not present.

I have multiple  Directory tag entries in my file1.txt a few of them are below:

```
<Directory "/web/htdocs">
<Directory />
.....
.....
<Directory "/web/cgi-bin">
```

With the below code I was able to a add the line  "Hi There" after only in the last Directory tag entry.

```
- name: Insert After string
  replace:
    path: "/tmp/file1.txt"
    state: present
    line: 'Hi There'
    insertafter: '^<Directory '
```

Results:

```
<Directory "/web/cgi-bin">
Hi There
```

However, I wish to get "Hi There" on the next line of each of the / all of the  Directory entries.

I understand that the "replace" module replaces all the occurances found. However, my limited knowledge says that the replace module needs a string to be replaced.

My requirement is not to replace anything but to insert a line after each of the Directory tag occurance are found.

Comment: Think of it as replacing the directory tag with an enhanced version, that has the original tag, the new line char and the phrase you want to insert.

Comment: I can you blockinfile for the same however as you see the directory tag has is different values so how can we include that Directory tag in the replace line? I'm not sure how to get that done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea: match any line like '' except if the next line is 'Hi there'. Replace with the same line followed by 'Hi there'. This is a regexp concept known as [negative lookahead](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookahead-assertions.php)

My `test.txt` file at start

```
<Directory "/web/htdocs">
<Directory />

<Directory "/web/cgi-bin">
<Directory />

<Directory "/some/other">
Hi there
</Directory>
```

My `test.yml` playbook

```
---
- name: Replace several lines
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Add 'Hi there' after directory def if not present
      replace:
        path: test.txt
        regexp: '^(<Directory ".*">\n)(?!Hi there)'
        replace: '\1Hi there\n'
```

First run:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [Replace several lines] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Add 'Hi there' after directory def if not present] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

`test.txt` file after first run. Note that lines where added only where needed.

```
<Directory "/web/htdocs">
Hi there
<Directory />

<Directory "/web/cgi-bin">
Hi there
<Directory />

<Directory "/some/other">
Hi there
</Directory>
```

Second run:

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [Replace several lines] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Add 'Hi there' after directory def if not present] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you can see, this time the file is unchanged since all possible lines were added.

Comment: is it possible to check Hi There not as the next line of Directory tag but anywhere between opening and closing Directory tag ? Will post a fresh  incase u can't help me here ?

Comment: Yes it is but you will need to tune the regexp, the negative lookahead and the back references. This makes the question quite different from orgin with a much more complex regexp. You might consider using a template in this case rather than modifying files in place.